# Does the integral $\int \frac{1}{(ax+b)(cx+d)} dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. 
I was wondering does the integreal 
$\int_A^{\infty} \frac{1}{(ax+b)(cx+d)} dx$ converge?
where the integrand is well defined for $x\geq A$?

I think it should because $1/x^2$ does... but I wasn't sure. Any info would be appreciated!

Comment: As long as the domain over which you integrate does not include the roots to $(ax+b)(cx+d)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it converges, since$$\left\lvert\frac1{(ax+b)(cx+d)}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac2{\lvert ac\rvert x^2}$$if $x$ is large enough and because $\int_A^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}$ converges.

Comment: Nitpick: your inequality only holds for positive parameters.

Comment: No, it is not a nitpick. I've edited my answer. Thank you.